# TrimStart() improperly truncates string

Tags: powershell, scripting

I wrote a script to backup bitlocker keys to Active Directory. The works great unless the Password ID starts with 'D'. Here is script

```
#Get recovery info
$recoveryinfo = manage-bde -protectors -get c:

#Check if bitlocker key could be located
If ($recoveryinfo -match 'All Key Protectors')
{
    $recoveryinfo 

    $arr = $recoveryinfo | Select-String -Pattern 'ID:'
    $arr[1] = $arr[1].ToString().TrimStart('ID: {')
    $arr[1] = $arr[1].ToString().TrimEnd('}')

    $key = $arr[1]
    $key = '{' + $key + '}'

    #Backup bitlocker key to active directory
    manage-bde -protectors -adbackup C: -id $key
}
Else
{
    $recoveryinfo
}
```

See https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFPs4.png. Notice how $key is missing 'd' as first character.

I've changed the script and it appears to work for all Password IDs but I would like to understand why my first attempt failed so that I may avoid the mistake in future scripts. Here is improved script:

```
#Get recovery info
$recoveryinfo = manage-bde -protectors -get c:

#Check if bitlocker key could be located
If ($recoveryinfo -match 'All Key Protectors')
{
    $recoveryinfo 

    $arr = $recoveryinfo | Select-String -Pattern 'ID:'
    $arr[1] = $arr[1].ToString().Substring(11, 36)

    $key = $arr[1]
    $key = '{' + $key + '}'

    #Backup bitlocker key to active directory
    manage-bde -protectors -adbackup C: -id $key
}
Else
{
    $recoveryinfo
}
```

See https://i.stack.imgur.com/cldPc.png. Notice how 'd' is present as first character.

Comment: If you have AD, why not set the group policies to do this automatically?

Comment: I did not know you could have group policy accomplish this. We're looking to implement MBAM in the future so this is kinda a temporary solution. Which policy do I need to configure to have this done through GP?

Comment: `Save BitLocker recovery information to Active Directory Domain Services` - link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679890(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation for [TrimStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx):

"The TrimStart method removes from the current string all leading characters that are in the trimChars parameter. The trim operation stops when a character that is not in trimChars is encountered."

"D" is a character in your array of characters to remove, so TrimStart does so, as it hasn't run into any characters that are not in your array yet.

In the future, please read the documentation on the method in question first.